# The Haskell "isPrefixOf" function done recursively

Tags: haskell

How can i write the "isPrefixOf" function recursively in Haskell?

I want to see if a list is a prefix of another list, but i have to do it recursively. I've been trying, but i can't find any suitable solution. 
Any ideas ?

Comment: So what have you been trying? Any thoughts at all, or are you looking for a general idea…?

Comment: i've been trying this : 
isPrefixOf :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
isPrefixOf [] [] = error "Empty Strings!"
isPrefixOf (x:xs) (y:ys)
                | x == y = isPrefixOf [xs][ys]
                | otherwise = False

Comment: In your code, `xs` is a list, say `[1,2,3,4]`.  When you call `isPrefixOf [xs] [ys]`, you are passing that list *wrapped in another list*, so `[xs]` is `[[1,2,3,4]]`, a list with one element (and that element is a list with 4 elements).

Comment: Just remove brackets: `| x == y = isPrefixOf xs ys`. Then only one bug left.

Comment: You could cheat and just look into the source : [isPrefixOf][1] . But first, try to listen Chris Tailor advise and do it by yourself


  [1]: http://lambda.haskell.org/platform/doc/current/ghc-doc/libraries/base-4.6.0.1/src/Data-List.html#isPrefixOf

Comment: so how can i solve that last bug?

Answer (score 6):

Here are some hints. There are three cases --

- The first list is empty (doesn't matter what the second one is).
- The first list is non-empty, but the second one is empty.
- Both lists are non-empty.

What should the result be in each of the three cases? Can you see how the third case can be treated recursively?

Comment: the first case would be isPrefixOf [] _ = error "First list is empty" the second case would be isPrefixOf _ [] = same type of error, but when they are both non-empty i see is recursive, but i'm not seeing how i can do it..

Comment: I don't agree with your first case or second case. Surely an empty list is a prefix of *every* other list?

Comment: The first two cases would return False, and the third one True. Is that it ?

Comment: You seem confused about what your function is supposed to do. Perhaps it would be helpful for you to write down what `isPrefixOf` does and write down a list of sample inputs and outputs? I agree that the second case should return `False`, because if the second list is empty, then the first list can't be a prefix of it (the only prefix of an empty list is an empty list). But I disagree with the other two (remember, the third one must be recursive!)

Comment: I'm confused because,i'm not seeing how i'm going to do it. The First line of the recursion would be | x == y = isPrefixOf xs ys. i understand because it verifies if x and y are equal and if they are, then they continue verifying for the next elements. but i struggling with the return statement, because i want to return true they are all equal when the first list ends, and the second one(larger one) doesn't. Otherwise return false